# Что использовать для ежедневной отправки уведомлений?

Tags: android

Мне нужно, чтобы приложение каждый день (когда оно закрыто) выполняла очень простые действия, по получению данных, и после этого отправляла уведомление. Подскажите, что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) - это API, который позволяет легко планировать отложенные асинхронные задачи, которые, как ожидается, будут выполняться, даже если приложение закрыто или устройство перезагружается. WorkManager API - это подходящая и рекомендуемая замена для всех предыдущих API фонового планирования Android, включая FirebaseJobDispatcher, GcmNetworkManager и Job Scheduler. WorkManager объединяет функции своих предшественников в современном, согласованном API, который работает до уровня API 14, но при этом учитывает срок службы батареи.

Собственно это все что вам нужно.